# How can I automate git rebase and merge in a happy-path scenario?

Tags: git, scripting, git-merge, git-rebase

#### Question

How can I automate the following steps with an intelligent script?

1. How do I programmatically detect if my `develop` is fast-forwardable to `origin develop`?
2. How do I programmatically detect if there are conflicts or not after doing `git rebase develop`?

#### Partial Progress

1. I have figured out how to get current branch name with this script below with a `grep` and `sed`.
   `my_curr_branch_name=$(git branch | grep '\*' | sed 's/^* //');echo "My branch name is $my_curr_branch_name"`
2. This is my work in progress for figuring out whether I am behind or up-to-date with the origin.
    I haven't fully gotten it working fully yet.
    `git status | grep 'Your branch is behind'`
    and
    `git status | grep 'Your branch is up-to-date'`
    to figure out if I am behind or not.

#### My Git Merge Process

Lets say I am on `feature/long-feature-name` branch in my git repository.

1. `git checkout develop`
2. `git fetch`
3. `git status` (**IF** `develop` is behind `origin` **and fast-forwardable**, continue. Stop otherwise.)
   **EXPLANATION:** This step is executed **for myself** to see if it is fast-forwardable.
   **QUESTION:** How do I programmatically detect if my `develop` is fast-forwardable to `origin develop`?
4. `git pull`
   **EXPLANATION:** I do `git pull` since I know I can safely fast-forward.
5. `git checkout feature/long-feature-name`
6. `git rebase develop` (**IF** no rebase conflicts continue. Otherwise, stop.)
   **QUESTION:** How do I programmatically detect if there are conflicts or not after doing `git rebase develop`?
7. `git checkout develop`
8. `git merge feature/long-feature-name`
9. `git push origin`

---

#### Functionality

1. The script needs to know which feature branch to go back to.

   - When the script starts running at **step #1**, it needs to remember which feature branch I am on at that point, so it can `git checkout feature/{branch-name}` on **step #5** and **step #8**.
2. The script needs to be smart to stop on the following conditions.

   - after **step #3** if my `develop` is not fast-forwardable.
   - after **step #6** if there are rebase conflicts.

---

#### `git flow feature finish`

I know `git flow feature finish` can do this, but not how I want it.
I don't want git flow script to `git merge --no-ff` which creates a merge point.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot like you want someone to write the script for you (it would, I think, help if you posted your own attempt).  I won't do that but I'll describe ways to achieve the items you asked about, and a flaw.

To find out what branch some work-tree is on, if it is on a named branch at all, use `git symbolic-ref` to read the value of `HEAD`.  This will fail if `HEAD` is not a symbolic (indirect) reference, i.e., if `HEAD` is currently detached and hence pointing directly to a commit.  If it does not fail, it will print (to standard output) the full name of the current branch, e.g., `refs/heads/master` or `refs/heads/feature/foo`.

The flaw is at step 4: `git pull` is `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or, if instructed, by `git rebase` instead).  This fetch happens after your step 2, possibly changing and hence invalidating the answer found in step 3.  For scripting purposes, `git pull` is always<sup>1</sup> wrong: use the two separate commands instead.

It's not clear to me what you want from step 3.  You can of course just run `git status`, but if the point is to discover fast-forward-ability, that's the wrong way to do it.  You can do it with `git rev-list --count` (which is part of what `git status` does) but it is simpler to run `git merge --ff-only` and detect failure, which occurs if and only if it is not possible to do a fast-forward.  By default, `git merge` will use the current branch's upstream setting; if there is none, no merge is possible (there is nothing to merge) and hence fast-forward merge is impossible as well, and hence this will fail.

(Failure is, as in any well-behaved Unix utility, reported as a nonzero exit status.)

If rebase conflicts occur in step 6, the `git rebase` command will exit with nonzero status, i.e., will fail, so conflict detection can be treated as a specific case of the general failure case.  (It's possible for the rebase to fail for other reasons, such as lack of disk space, but probably you want to stop here as well.)

The rest should be easy, given the above.

---

<sup>1</sup>(G&S icon here) What, always?  Yes always! ... Well, hardly ever! (OK, that didn't quite work. :-) )

Comment: I updated my question to be a bit easier to understand, and included my work in progress.  Can you take a look at it again please? Currently, I have a simple sequence of commands that somewhat works based on the non-zero exit code you mentioned, but I don't think is perfect. See this one: `git checkout develop && git fetch && git pull --ff-only && git checkout - && git rebase develop`

Comment: That sequence is nearly right (replace `git pull` with `git merge`), with the flaw that if any step fails before the `git checkout -`, you're left on `develop`.  (Relying on `git checkout -` is a bit lazy but sometimes lazy is good :-) )